# Batch File to Move Files based on List of Strings

Tags: batch-file

I have searched for days with results of similar circumstances but none that exactly addresses my problem.

Problem: I have 10,000 files in C:\Data folder. They all have a file name such as 1234_File_Log_Date_Time.csv. 1234 is a serial number. I have a list of multiple serial in a SN.txt file. I would like to have a batch file read SN.txt, then copy the files found in C:\Test Data based on this list to another directory of C:\My Data. There are no duplicate files to contend with.

I have never written a batch file in my life so be gentle haha.

Comment: If you have tried any code already, please edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 1):

*I have never written a batch file in my life*... Read [Command-Line Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc754340(v=ws.11)) or [Windows Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands).
For an initial look, start with a simple batch script which could appear like

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
pushd "C:\Data"
for /f "delims=" %%G in (SN.txt) do (
  echo "%%~G"
)
popd
pause
```

Then replace the `echo "%%~G"` line (step by step) with

- `if exist "%%~G_*.csv" dir /B "%%~G_*.csv"` (to **see** *file names* that are to be copied);
- `if exist "%%~G_*.csv" echo copy /B "%%~G_*.csv" "C:\My Data\"` (to **see**  *commands* that are to be performed);
- `if exist "%%~G_*.csv" copy /B "%%~G_*.csv" "C:\My Data\"` (final edit to **execute** the commands).

**Additional resources** (required reading for any batch scripter):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Comment: Thank you JosefZ. This script works perfectly. I will definitely read up on some of the resources you provided.